# unable to deploy apps on mobilefirst studio

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

I am using the IBM mobilefirst studio. And I am able to create apps and run the apps as build all environments, but i cant get past run on MobileFirst Development Server...

```
> [ERROR   ] C:\Users\mec%20i.t\workspace\MobileFirstServerConfig\servers\worklight\workarea\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\73\data\cache\com.ibm.ws.app.manager_93\.cache\WEB-INF\lib\ibm_web20_wink_no_abdera_no_jackson-1.1.0.0-20110422.jar (The system cannot find the path specified)
[ERROR   ] C:\Users\mec%20i.t\workspace\MobileFirstServerConfig\servers\worklight\workarea\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\73\data\cache\com.ibm.ws.app.manager_93\.cache\WEB-INF\lib\ibm_web20_wink_no_abdera_no_jackson-1.1.0.0-20110422.jar (The system cannot find the path specified)
[ERROR   ] Uncaught.init.exception.thrown.by.servlet 
[ERROR   ] C:\Users\mec%20i.t\workspace\MobileFirstServerConfig\servers\worklight\workarea\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\73\data\cache\com.ibm.ws.app.manager_93\.cache\WEB-INF\lib\ibm_web20_wink_no_abdera_no_jackson-1.1.0.0-20110422.jar (The system cannot find the path specified)
[ERROR   ] C:\Users\mec%20i.t\workspace\MobileFirstServerConfig\servers\worklight\workarea\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\73\data\cache\com.ibm.ws.app.manager_93\.cache\WEB-INF\lib\ibm_web20_wink_no_abdera_no_jackson-1.1.0.0-20110422.jar (The system cannot find the path specified)
[ERROR   ] Uncaught.init.exception.thrown.by.servlet 
[ERROR   ] C:\Users\mec%20i.t\workspace\MobileFirstServerConfig\servers\worklight\workarea\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\73\data\cache\com.ibm.ws.app.manager_93\.cache\WEB-INF\lib\ibm_web20_wink_no_abdera_no_jackson-1.1.0.0-20110422.jar (The system cannot find the path specified)
[ERROR   ] C:\Users\mec%20i.t\workspace\MobileFirstServerConfig\servers\worklight\workarea\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\73\data\cache\com.ibm.ws.app.manager_93\.cache\WEB-INF\lib\ibm_web20_wink_no_abdera_no_jackson-1.1.0.0-20110422.jar (The system cannot find the path specified)
[ERROR   ] Uncaught.init.exception.thrown.by.servlet 
[ERROR   ] C:\Users\mec%20i.t\workspace\MobileFirstServerConfig\servers\worklight\workarea\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\73\data\cache\com.ibm.ws.app.manager_93\.cache\WEB-INF\lib\ibm_web20_wink_no_abdera_no_jackson-1.1.0.0-20110422.jar (The system cannot find the path specified)
[ERROR   ] C:\Users\mec%20i.t\workspace\MobileFirstServerConfig\servers\worklight\workarea\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\73\data\cache\com.ibm.ws.app.manager_93\.cache\WEB-INF\lib\ibm_web20_wink_no_abdera_no_jackson-1.1.0.0-20110422.jar (The system cannot find the path specified)
[ERROR   ] Uncaught.init.exception.thrown.by.servlet 
[ERROR   ] C:\Users\mec%20i.t\workspace\MobileFirstServerConfig\servers\worklight\workarea\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\73\data\cache\com.ibm.ws.app.manager_93\.cache\WEB-INF\lib\ibm_web20_wink_no_abdera_no_jackson-1.1.0.0-20110422.jar (The system cannot find the path specified)
[ERROR   ] C:\Users\mec%20i.t\workspace\MobileFirstServerConfig\servers\worklight\workarea\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\73\data\cache\com.ibm.ws.app.manager_93\.cache\WEB-INF\lib\ibm_web20_wink_no_abdera_no_jackson-1.1.0.0-20110422.jar (The system cannot find the path specified)
[ERROR   ] Uncaught.init.exception.thrown.by.servlet 
[ERROR   ] C:\Users\mec%20i.t\workspace\MobileFirstServerConfig\servers\worklight\workarea\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\73\data\cache\com.ibm.ws.app.manager_93\.cache\WEB-INF\lib\ibm_web20_wink_no_abdera_no_jackson-1.1.0.0-20110422.jar (The system cannot find the path specified)
[ERROR   ] C:\Users\mec%20i.t\workspace\MobileFirstServerConfig\servers\worklight\workarea\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\73\data\cache\com.ibm.ws.app.manager_93\.cache\WEB-INF\lib\ibm_web20_wink_no_abdera_no_jackson-1.1.0.0-20110422.jar (The system cannot find the path specified)
[ERROR   ] Uncaught.init.exception.thrown.by.servlet
```

Seeking help to solve this.

Comment: Then you can start by mentioning: Your Eclipse version (Java EE or not? which version?), installed Java version, ...

Comment: my eclipse version is juno

Comment: Use either Kepler or Luna with MobileFirst Platform.

Comment: u r saying i should change from juno to either kepler or luna?

Comment: Yes, that is what I am saying. In addition to my answer below regarding the sapces in the path.

Comment: ok tank u lemme try it and get back to u

Comment: tank u guys soo much i didnt change the eclipse i only made sure the were no spaces in my workspace path... thank you Idan

Comment: This is similar to [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28112479/unable-to-deploy-helloworld-application-to-mobilefirst-development-server][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28112479/unable-to-deploy-helloworld-application-to-mobilefirst-development-server

Comment: @Abdul I also had this problem, your question helped me in better understanding it and finding a solution

Comment: @FabrizioBertoglio you welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things to try:

1. If you're using Java 8, downgrade to 7 to 6
2. Since you're using Windows:

   - try with a workspace path that does not contain spaces
   - try with a shorter path (put the workspace and eclipse straight in C:)

I suspect it may be due to the spaces in the path: :\Users\mec%20i.t\workspace\