# error when Running android app in mobile first platform server says HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://localhost:10080 refused

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

I am new to MFP, i am trying to do a [tutorial](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-6-3/authentication-security/custom-authenticator-login-module/custom-authenticator-login-module-native-android-applications/) i am trying this in my laptop provided by office . i downloaded native project in to my eclipse and trying to run it and then i got errors in LogCat. attached image got error log.[image]. and following are the settings in my wlclient.properties

```
wlServerProtocol = http
wlServerHost = localhost
wlServerPort = 10080
wlServerContext = /NativeCustomLoginModule/
wlAppId = AndroidNativeCustomLoginModule
wlAppVersion = 1.0
wlEnvironment = Androidnative
wlUid = wY/mbnwKTDDYQUvuQCdSgg==
wlPlatformVersion = 6.3.0.00.20141121-0732
```

when i run this and see output in AVD it shows like below
[image]

did i miss any setting or is it a problem in office provided laptop. from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28112479/unable-to-deploy-helloworld-application-to-mobilefirst-development-server) i got to know that its a problem in office provided laptop. what might be the issue?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to find your IP address (open CMD and use the command `ipconfig`) instead of `localhost`. Use it as the `wlServerHost` value in the wlclient.properties file, located in the Android project.

Comment: i have tried previously the same which u suggested and just now again after your comment , even though there are no errors in logcat connection is not established android emulator screen shows "connection failure, the service is currently not available"

Comment: no i tried and got ip address many times  run->cmd->ipconfig under IPv4 Address. what about the link i gave at the end of my question is it anything to do with office laptop envi?

Comment: `ipconfig` solved it for me. Somehow `mfpdev app register` does not offer to choose a default IP anymore.